# Exception handling and coercion

Tags: c++, exception, language-design, coercion, subtyping

```
try
{
    throw Derived();
}
catch (Base&)
{
    std::cout << "subtyping\n";
}

try
{
    throw "lol";
}
catch (std::string)
{
    std::cout << "coercion\n";
}
```

Output:

```
subtyping
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*'
```

Why does exception handling play nice with subtyping, but not with coercion?

Comment: New objects aren't created when you throw an exception to try to match an exception handler.

Comment: Because `Derived()` **is** a `Base` and can be bound by a `Base&`, but `"coercion"` is not a `std::string`. The catch clauses capture the *existing* object.

Comment: What would happen if there was a second catch block taking a type `myOwnString`? Wouldn't that be ambiggy?

Comment: @Pubby Well, what if there was a second catch block taking a different Base?

Comment: Any particular reason why this question still doesnt have an accepted answer?

Comment: @elmes I usually accept answers in bursts. Are you on a rep hunt? :)

Comment: @FredOverflow Just wondered what else could I add, or what did I describe wrong..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Catching thrown exceptions is quite different from passing arguments to functions.
There are similarities, but there are also subtle differences.

The 3 main differences are:

- exceptions are always copied at least once (not possible to avoid at all)
- `catch` clauses are examined in the order they are declared (not best-fit)
- **they are subject to fewer forms of type conversions**:

  - inheritance-based coversions,
  - conversion from a typed to an untyped pointer (`const void*` catches any pointer)

Any other kind of conversion is not allowed (e.g. `int` to `double`, or implicit `const char*` to `string` - your example).

**Regarding your question in the comment**
Suppose a hierarchy exists:

```
class Base {}; 
class Derived: public Base {};
class Base2 {};
class Leaf: public Derived, public Base2 {};
```

Now depending on the order of `catch` clauses, an appropriate block will be executed.

```
try {
    cout << "Trying ..." << endl;
    throw Leaf();

} catch (Base& b) {
    cout << "In Base&";

} catch (Base2& m) {
    cout << "In Base2&"; //unreachable due to Base&

} catch (Derived& d) {
    cout << "In Derived&";  // unreachable due to Base& and Base2&
}
```

If you switch `Base` and `Base2` catch order you will notice a different behavior.
If `Leaf` inherited privately from `Base2`, then `catch Base2&` would be unreachable no matter where placed (assuming we throw a `Leaf`)

Generally it's simple: **order matters.**

Answer (score 8):

Paragraph 15.3/3 of the C++11 Standard defines the exact conditions for a handler to be a match for a certain exception object, and these do not allow *user-defined conversions*:

> A handler is a match for an exception object of type `E` if
>
> — The handler is of type `cv T` or `cv T&` and `E` and `T` are the same type (ignoring the top-level `cv`-qualifiers),
>   or
>
> — the handler is of type `cv T` or `cv T&` and `T` is an unambiguous public base class of `E`, or
>
> — the handler is of type `cv1 T* cv2` and `E` is a pointer type that can be converted to the type of the
>   handler by either or both of
>
> - a standard pointer conversion (4.10) not involving conversions to pointers to private or protected
>     or ambiguous classes
> - a qualification conversion
>
> — the handler is a pointer or pointer to member type and `E` is `std::nullptr_t`.
>
> [ ... ]